# On page load change locale depending on queryParam

Tags: next.js, i18next

In Next.js i have a query param `?local=en`
When any page loads i want to change its locale depending on what is in `?local=en`

What is the best way doing this with next.js?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

check the docs

[Internationalized Routing](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing)

**other solutions**

as [next.js docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app) says, app.tsx does not support Next.js Data Fetching methods like getStaticProps or getServerSideProps.
that means you can't give the local from query param in app.tsx and decide for page datas or styles

so you should get the query param from nextjs data fetching methods and pass it as a prop to the Next JS page.

wrap the layout inside the next pages and pass the query to it.

```
// pages/index.js
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {

    return {
        props: { 
           local: context.query.local
       },
     };
    }

function Index(props) {
    const { local } = props;

    return (
     <Layout local={local}>
       <main>
          <div> content </div>
       </main>
     </Layout>
     )
}
```

**Suggestion**

i think these links will be helpful

[react query as a state management](https://tkdodo.eu/blog/react-query-as-a-state-manager)

[react query SSR](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/guides/ssr)

[reduxt toolkit ssr](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/server-side-rendering)